# How to make your Android App pretty for release

Tags: android, android-layout

So, I have my app prepared in a very crude format. It does what it is suppose to do. But, I am an Application developer, but never really thought of making my app BEAUTIFUL in the front end.

What steps, frameworks, styles, themes, corners etc can I implement to make my App pretty. I want to release it to the market and would like my users to feel good about it to.

Comment: put some bounty on your code and somebody will make your layout pretty for you or hire an designer which will give you some designs that you can implement or ask somebody to implement for you.

Comment: Your question doesn't directly relate to programming. Try http://ux.stackexchange.com/ where the discussions are about the UX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least skim through the new [Android Design site](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).  But why not just look at other applications that you think look nice and start getting ideas?

On the other hand, if your program is currently functional, maybe the current simplistic design isn't as bad as you think.  Or at least, it's probably not that hard to make it worse.  For now, you could work on the parts that you know are the worst or where the users will spend most of their time.  You can expand out from there later with updates.

If you are talking about more rudimentary methods... try to prepare as much as you can for the possibility that you will have multiple layouts for different device sizes, for landscape, etc.  Do your best to make sure that when you need to change colors, you don't have to go into all of your layouts and change them there!  You will be much better off if you can just change the colors in a separate colors file.  Keep things logical, but don't be afraid to take small steps.